# Including C DLL with C#

Tags: c#, c, dll

I've written a C DLL and I'm trying to integrate it into a C# WPF program.

I believe I am nearly there, but there are a few functions in the DLL that I'm having trouble specifying in C#.

The way that the DLL is included is:

```
[DllImport("GyroLib.dll")]
```

The library has around 30 functions in it. If I only list some of them then everything compiles and builds OK, eg:

```
[DllImport("GyroLib.dll")]
public static extern double getRoll();
public static extern double getHeading();
public static extern double getBadPitch();
```

There are some functions that are not so trivial to include though, that give me errors:

```
[DllImport("GyroLib.dll")]
public static extern double** getCovMatrix();
public static extern void init(double R0[][3], double deltat, double biasx, double biasy, double biasz);
public static extern void initCF(double R0[][3], double deltat, double* biasx, double* biasy, double* biasz, int buflen);
```

I think the errors centre on the `R0[][3]` C syntax, and possibly the pointers need changing to `ref` or `out`.

How should I turn these function declarations to be C# like so that I can use the functions in my WPF app?

Comment: Have a dig around for windows functions that have similar signatures and then see whether anyone has put them on pinvoke.net

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(VS.80).aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforarraysanchor3 may help?

Comment: The two-dimensional arrays of doubles (with static second dimension) can be passed as a single-dimensional array, with the `MarshalAs` attribute correctly defined (IIRC, `LPArray` should work). The big problem will be the `double**`. You might be better off building a C++/CLI DLL to serve as glue between the two.